# Ajax Auto complete is not able to set TextBox Value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am having a Textbox for which i am using Ajax Autocomplete function.

The function is working correctly and is fetching the value from Database and also populating the value in TextBox.

But i am having a button which fires a query and fetches some value in a Label. This query fetches value using the selected auto complete value.

When i tried to debug i found that the textbox value used was null which is causing issues. So i is possible that though the value of Textbox is populated but is not getting set.

Here is my code for AJAX.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    //data: "{'tagName':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearchDir').value + "'}",  here tagName should be same to the variable name in fn
    function SearchText() {
        $("#txtSearchDir").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                //alert('inside');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "SearchPage.aspx/autoTagSearch",
                    data: "{'tagName':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearchDir').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                    autoFocus: true
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                    document.getElementById('txtSearchDir').value = "";
                       // alert(url);
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does the button click performs an Ajax request or  post back a request to server

Comment: No ajax is used only over the text box the button just performs a search and returns set of values and prints it in label

Comment: Ok, As soon as you select a value from autocomplete it get filled in the textbox but when you click the submit button that does a post back and call an click event the textbox value gets lost n result is either empty or null.

Comment: Yup appears that way but that should not happen

Comment: This usually happens when someone try to fill data during page load from database and failed to include **IsPostback** property inside page load event. Do check if you are trying to populate data at page load or calling any method without **!IsPostbak** property that is assiging a emplty string like Text1.Text = string.Empty;

Comment: OK thank you very much now I understood oops I missed the !ispostback part in main page code foolish me thank you that will help

Comment: Welcome, hope this sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to save the selected value into a hidden textbox on the page so it is available even after other events fire.

you do it with `function autoCompleteItemSelected(source, eventArgs)` event.

(there's an old post on the web somewhere that i used for this that works well but i can't find it now.)

you can get the selected value with `eventArgs.get_value();` then set your hidden textbox.